# GooglePlacesAPI internal error occurred

Tags: google-places-api

Error Domain=com.google.places.ErrorDomain Code=-3 "An internal error occurred in the Places API library. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/support)." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An internal error occurred in the Places API library. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/support)., NSUnderlyingError=0x618000a56f20 {Error Domain=com.google.places.server.ErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000650aa0 {Error Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=500 "Backend Error" UserInfo={GTLRStructuredError=GMSx_GTLRErrorObject 0x60800045ec00: {message:"Backend Error" errors:[1] code:500}, NSLocalizedDescription=Backend Error}}}}}

Same google api premium account with different key for iOS and Android.
Anyone experienced this?

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188872&s=created_time:desc

Comment: I think is down right now

Comment: yes we have the same problem since 2-3 days...

Comment: google replied 10min ago, one of their servers is down https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38492985

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Finally, the fix was pushed and confirmed to be working!